# c++ : Fast searching in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a `2D array` which I use in my code in  the following way:

Searching for a particular entry takes lot of time whereas I want to reduce the time for searching elements. Can anyone please suggest me what optimization I can do to reduce the time of searching in this 2D array?

```
 for( counter1=0; counter1< size ; ++counter1)
    {   
    int index= GVector[counter1];
    SingleTableEntries NewNextState=NewSingleTable[Next][index];

    Next=NewNextState.Next_State;
    if(NewNextState.accept1==1 )
    {
        return 1;           
    }

    index= GuideVector[counter1+1];

    NewNextState=NewSingleTable[Next][index];

    NextState_chunk2=NewNextState.Next_State;
    if(NewNextState.accept1==1 )
    {
        return 1;       
    }       
    //code
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Given an n x n matrix, where every row and column is sorted in increasing order. Given a number x, how to decide whether this x is in the matrix. The designed algorithm should have linear time complexity.

1. Start with top right element
2. Loop: compare this element e with x
   i) if they are equal then return its position
   ii) e < x then move it to down (if out of bound of matrix then break return false)
   iii) e > x then move it to left (if out of bound of matrix then break return false)
3. repeat the i), ii) and iii) till you find element or returned false

The function below searches the element x in mat[][]. If the element is found, then prints its position and returns true, otherwise prints "not found" and returns false.

```
int search(int mat[4][4], int n, int x) {
    int i = 0, j = n-1;  //set indexes for top right element
    while ( i < n && j >= 0 ) {
        if ( mat[i][j] == x ) {
            printf("\n Found at %d, %d", i, j);
            return 1;
        }
        if ( mat[i][j] > x )
        j--;
        else //  if mat[i][j] < x
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n Element not found");
    return 0;  // if ( i==n || j== -1 )
}

int main() {
    int mat[4][4] = {   {10, 20, 30, 40},
                        {15, 25, 35, 45},
                        {27, 29, 37, 48},
                        {32, 33, 39, 50},
                    };
    search(mat, 4, 29);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Time Complexity: O(n)

The above approach will also work for m x n matrix (not only for n x n). Complexity would be O(m + n).

Comment: Well I want to access a particular value at the indexes I obtained. I know the indexes like where the element is located but I don't know which value is located at that indexes. Can you please modify the above code according to this scenario

Comment: If you know the indexes, why do you have to search? Just read the value?